# Declaring an array in a constructor: does it result in a dangling pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers

This is likely a simple question. Consider:

```
class foo
{
  int * p;

  public:
    foo(int i)
    { int t[i]; p = t; }

 };
```

Is p a dangling pointer once the constructor goes out of scope? Do I *have* to do it with new[]?

Tia

Comment: In short yes.  But instead of new use a standard container (e.g. `std::vector`), or a smart pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is `p` a dangling pointer once the constructor goes out of scope?

Yes, the lifetime of `t` ends when you leave the constructor. Also, variable length arrays like `t[i]` are a gcc/clang extension and not part of standard C++.

> Do I have to do it with `new[]`?

No! You should use the much easier and better `std::vector` instead!

```
class foo {
  std::vector<int> p;

  public:
    foo(int i) : p(i) {}        
};
```

You can access its elements with `p[k]` just as you would with a C-style array, but do not need to worry about that nasty memory management.

See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) for a full documentation of what you can do with `std::vector`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. And you're right, there's no reason not to use STL here.